# In Rails, what's the difference between to_label and to_s?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, what's the difference between `to_label` and `to_s`? Especially in the context of displaying model info in views. I know that if you define `to_s` you don't have to explicitly call `Model.to_s` in views. What's the advantage of using `to_label` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to_label has been deprecated, you can't find it from the Rails3 source

Answer (score 0):

I believe the difference was that `to_label` did some magic in that converting values such as object class names `to_s` where as `to_s` just converts an object to a string.